# Bizarre list comprehension behavior

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm usually not a fan of using the word bizarre as I feel it's not very descriptive, but I cannot figure out what it happening with this list comprehension, and it seems trivial.

```
current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
relative_paths = ["/testdir/extension.foo, /testdir/nested/extension.foo"]
absolute_paths = [(current_path+item) for item in relative_paths]
```

I would assume the output of this would be something like:

```
absolute_paths = [absolute_path, absolute_path]
```

but instead the output is:

```
absolute_paths = [absolute_path, relative_path]
```

The list comprehension does nothing to the second entry, and honestly this baffles me. I've never experienced anything like this. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to split the paths in `relative_paths`. Look harder.